# Loop through array: CCAction for every element, but only one callback after actions are finished

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I use a UIPanGestureRecognizer to detect pans / swipes. When the swipe is complete and the touch ends, I run a CCAction on 12 CCNodeColors in an NSSet.

While the CCActions are running, I disable the UIPanGestureRecognizer, so that the user can't swipe while the previous animation is still running. After the CCActions are finished, I enable the UIPanGestureRecognizer again.

**Problem:** The `*callback` action runs 12 times. So the UIPanGestureRecognizer is enabled before the other 11 actions are completed. What's the best way to only run the `*callback` after the last action `*move` has finished?

(Or is it a problem at all?)

Here's the simplified code:

```
if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded ) {

    sender.enabled = NO;

    for (CCNodeColor *node in nodeSet) {

        CCActionMoveTo *move = [CCActionMoveTo actionWithDuration:1.0 position:newPosition];

        CCActionCallBlock *callback = [CCActionCallBlock actionWithBlock:^{
            sender.enabled = YES;
        }];

        CCActionSequence *seq = [CCActionSequence actionWithArray:@[move, callback]];
        [node runAction:seq];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a 'simplified' possible answer

```
if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded ) {

    sender.enabled = NO;

    for (CCNodeColor *node in nodeSet) {
        CCActionMoveTo *move = [CCActionMoveTo actionWithDuration:1.0 position:newPosition];
       [node runAction:move];
    }

    CCActionDelay *wait = [CCActionDelay actionWithDuration:1.05f]; 
    CCActionCallBlock *callback = [CCActionCallBlock actionWithBlock:^{
        sender.enabled = YES;
    }];
    CCActionSequence *seq = [CCActionSequence actionWithArray:@[wait, callback]];
    [self runAction:seq];

}
```